# Can't sort by date in view

Tags: views, 6

I have the simple view to display a list of nodes of a particular type. But I can't get it to sort by post date! I tried over and over, ascending and descending and it just won't sort!

I don't know what to do...

In the preview this is the sql statement:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.created AS node_created
  FROM node node  WHERE (node.type in ('homepage_feat_video')) AND (node.status <> 0)
```

There is no sort directive. But I added a sort for sure!

EDIT: discovered that when I change the style to something other than table - it works. but why doesn't it work in a table?

Comment: Can u give screenshot of views

Comment: Tables expect to be sorted by the columns on display. Set the date column as default sort in the table configuration.

Answer (score 1):

OP asks for D6. For D6 make sure you have the latest version of the date and the views module. Older versions have a bug that tends to "forget" the sort part of the SQL statement.